# Hardware-accelerated alpha-enabled in-memory put-bitmap on linux?

Tags: graphics, hardware-acceleration

Would live to draw bitmap 1 onto bitmap 2, and bitmap 1 alpha-channel must be used.
Both are in memory, both a RGBA.

I need this operation be as fast as possible. So hardware acceleraton would be very helpful.

Actually There will be thousands of small bitmaps drawn on one big bitmap (similar to text rendering). I need to save the result to disk. What library/function could you recommend?

I was thinking about something like OpenGL+CreateTexture, but it's been long ago when I wrote my OpenGL "helloworld"... And yes, it's C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply doing 2D blits, you should consider using OpenVG (instead of OpenGL).

You have mentioned Linux, but not the hardware platform. If it's an embedded processor, OpenVG support is usually pretty good. Can't say the same for desktop (x86), where you'd have to use OpenGL.

Comment: I would like to have it cross-architectural. So that it runs on most possible linuxes.

Comment: In that case, OpenGL is probably your best bet. OpenGL is supported on Windows, Linux and OS X.